# Multiple views in the same Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, layout, swipe

I'm developing a Tinder-like Android application and I am using [this](https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards) library to implement the card swiping functionality.
For the swipe screen, I use this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        style="@style/BackgroundStyle"
        android:padding="16dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <com.lorentzos.flingswipe.SwipeFlingAdapterView
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:rotation_degrees="16"
                    app:max_visible="2"
                    app:min_adapter_stack="1"
                    android:id="@+id/swipeView"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <fragment
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/tabmenu"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and inflating it in the activity:

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipe);
    ...
```

I am now planning on adding different types of cards (that have different designs) and am facing the problem of using multiple views for the same activity.
For instance, one card will have a person on it. Another card might have a question, etc. Is there any smart way of using different views in the same activity? The intended functionality is that you see 4-5 cards with people on them, then you see a card with a question / feedback request, then you should see people again, and so on.

The Swipe library uses an ArrayAdapter to keep the objects that represent cards, and the layout of the card is given by the getView() function:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardlayout, parent, false);
        ...
```

Is there any way to make this load different views according to some input/attribute?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is possible.

Check this two methods from adapter

- `getViewTypeCount()`

  > Returns the number of types of Views that will be created by
  >   getView(int, View, ViewGroup).
- `getItemViewType(int position)`

  > Get the type of View that will be created by getView(int, View,
  >   ViewGroup) for the specified item.

Override `getViewTypeCount` and set the number of different views for your adapter. And in `getItemViewType` check your item, and return a type for that item.

You could use it like this

```
// Using two different layouts 
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount()
{
    return 2;
}

// Get the type of item  
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
    if (arrayList.get(position).isUserType())
    {
        return ITEM_USER;
    }
    else
    {
        return ITEM_PHOTO;
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (getItemViewType(position) == ITEM_USER)
    {
        // Inflate first layout
    }
    else
    {
        // Inflate second layout
    }
}
```

If you need any further help / explanation, let me know.

Comment: Thanks man :) this looks like a really good solution! Will start working on it now

Comment: Your welcome, if you will have any problems, let me know! :)